# How to capture unset REQUEST values in PHP

Tags: php, xml, post

I'm really unsure if this is even possible but we have an issue where we control an interface that is having XML posted in to it via HTTP post in the form of `www.url.com/script.php?xml=<xmlgoeshere>`.  That is then URL encoded and passed in to us, and we decode and parse it.

Except I have one client who just refuses to url encode their incoming code, which works fine except for when the XML hits an ampersand, at which point everything is being parsed as an end of the xml variable.

`www.url.com/script.php?xml=<xmlstart...foo&bar.../>`

The end result being that I have XML being POST/GET'd into the xml variable as normal, and then I lose half of the incoming content because of the ampersand.

Now I know that's expected/proper behavior, my question is, is it possible to capture the `&bar.../>` segment of this code, so that if we hit a known error I can crowbar this into working anyways?  I know this is non-ideal but I'm at my wit's end dealing with the outside party.

**UPDATE**

Ok so I was totally confused.  After grabbing the server variables as mentioned below, it looks like I'm not getting the querystring, but that's because on the query they're submitting it has:

```
 [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 [QUERY_STRING] =>
```

That being the case, is the above behavior still to be expected?  Is their a way to get the raw form input in this case?  Thanks to the below posters for their help

Comment: Is `xml` the only variable that is sent to your script? Cause you could just manually parse `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: The real solution. Tell your client that they have to follow the standard, or it won't work.

Comment: Your update confuses me. What *exactly* are they sending? `POST /script.php`, *no* query parameters, and a form-encoded body? Is the problem here really invalid XML rather than a url-encoding problem?  Note that if they really want to they can just send the raw XML without encoding or `xml=` as long as they set `Content-Type: application/xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only parameter you use is `xml=`, and it's always at the front, and there are no other parameters, you can do something like this pseudocode:

```
if (count($_GET)>1 or is_not_well_formed_xml($_GET['xml'])) {
   $xml = substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 4);
   if (is_not_well_formed_xml($xml)) {
       really_fail();
   }
}
```

However, you should tell the client to fix their code, especially since it's *so easy* for them to comply with the standard! You might still get trouble if the xml contains a `?` or a `#`, since php or the web server may get confused about where the query string starts (messing up your `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, and either PHP, the client's code or an intermediary proxy or web server may get confused about the `#`, because that usually is the beginning of a fragment.

E.g., Something like this might be impossible to transmit reliably in a query parameter:

```
<root><link href="http://example.org/?querystring#fragment"/></root>
```

So tell them to fix their code. It's almost certainly incredibly easy for them to do so!

### UPDATE

There's some confusion about whether this is a GET or POST. If they send a POST with x-www-form-urlencoded body, you can substitute `file_get_contents('php://input')` for `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in the code above.

Comment: Coming back to this 4 months later, using `file_get_contents('php://input')` was a slam dunk and resolved the issue.  Thanks Francis

Answer (score 2):

You'd be hard pressed to do it, if it's even possible, because the fragments of a query string take the format foo=bar with the & character acting as the separator.  This means that you'd get an unpredictible $_GET variable created that would take the key name of everything between the & and the next = (assuming there even is one) that would take the value from the = to the next & or the end of the string.

It might be possible to attempt to parse the $_GET array in some way to recover the lost meaning but it would never be all that reliable.  You might have more luck trying to parse $_SERVER ['QUERY_STRING'], but that's not guaranteed to succeed either, and would be a hell of a lot of effort for a problem that can be avoided just by the client using the API properly.

And for me, that's the main point. If your client refuses to use your API in the way you tell them to use it, then it's ultimately their problem if it doesn't work, not yours.  Of course you should accommodate your clients to a reasonable standard, but that doesn't mean bending over backwards for them just because they refuse to accommodate your needs or technical standards that have been laid down for the good of everyone.

Comment: I gave this the answer vote only to focus on the fact that ultimately the answer here wound up being "USE THE API THE WAY WE TOLD YOU TO".  Never figured it out but I'm going to keep pounding my head on the desk and if I figure out what they ARE doing I'll be sure to update the thread.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

YES, Its possible. Using `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`.

For your url `www.url.com/script.php?xml=<xmlstart...foo&bar.../>`, `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` should contain, `xml=<xmlstart...foo&bar.../>`;

The following code should extract the xml data.

```
$pos=strpos($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], 'xml');
$xml="";
if($pos!==false){
    $xml = substr($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], $pos+strlen("xml="));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the query string will be parsed for & and = characters. If you know where your = character will be after the "bar" key then you may be able to capture the value of the rest of the string. However if you hit more & you are going to need to know the full content of the incoming message body. If you do then you should be able to get the rest of the content.